# MacOS Ventura: Unable to replace application bundle in /Applications

Tags: macos, macos-ventura, osx-gatekeeper

I am trying to replace an application bundle at `/Applications/example.app` with an updated version of the same bundle on OSX Ventura and I get `Operation not permitted`. Both bundles are signed and notarized with the same identity. Inside both applications bundles I have a tool called `swap` which takes two paths, and does a `renamex_np(pathA, pathB, RENAME_SWAP)` which results in `Operation not permitted`. I can run `codesign -dvvv <appbundle>` for both app bundles, and can see the Authority, TeamIdentifier, Identity all set, and are the same for both. I also do this same command on the `swap` app, and see Authority, and TeamIdentifier match the bundle, with `Identifier=swap`.

The notification pops up saying "Application X was prevented from updating or deleting apps on your Mac."

Some notes:

- If I allow the app under App Management, it works.
- The app bundle app can modify itself however it wishes.
- [For signed apps, macOS allows apps from the same developer — those sharing the same Team ID — to modify the app’s bundle.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsupdatesecuritypolicy#discussion) This does not seem to be working.
- [WWDC2022 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10096#). Repeats the above point: apps signed with same Team ID can update each other. Jump to 5min. Signing issue?
- Console log shows TCC (Transparency, Control and Consent) `kTCCServiceSystemPolicyAppBundles` is blocking the application. TCC was extended to /Applications folder in Ventura.

Help! Thanks

Comment: I would check if the entitlement com.apple.security.inherit is set to true. This entitlement allows a helper tool to inherit the same entitlements as its parent process.

Comment: Hi @djmonki, [that property](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) only matters if sandboxing is enabled. However I'm not using app sandboxing.

Comment: How was the application installed in the first place? By drag-and-drop, or .pkg?

Comment: DMG drag drop to applications folder, then launched.

Comment: Who's the owner? You or system?

Comment: % ls -l /Applications | grep example.app =>>
drwxr-xr-x@  3 fionbio  admin

Comment: I know it's not a solution, but did you try manually adding you .app to the list in Privacy > App Management. Does it work then?

Comment: Yes (minlenminlen)

Comment: Holy shit I might have figured it out. With nothing blocked under app management, I started thinking there was a bug in the os hit by the breadth of varied attempts, so I did a reboot, clicked the update mechanism in the app, and it worked.  I'll slim out the process, and triple check to be sure I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the massive set of evidence that suggested everything was in-place, I starting thinking the Gatekeeper mechanism was out of sync with reality, and did a reboot. After this I ran the application, hit update, and the package was replaced without issue.

Some notes:

- The application is standalone (plist or entitlements are not required).
- We are actually using [replaceItemAt...](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412432-replaceitematurl) over `renamex_np`. Be sure to do this operation for targets on the same volume!